# Tearing-Down a development deployment in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, continuous-delivery

I have a Jenkins CD pipeline that deploys a test environment to a Kubernetes cluster.
I want to be able to easily tear down that environment as a manual action from Jenkins.

I come from Gitlab CI where there notion of [Environments](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/environments/#stop-an-environment-by-using-the-ui) enable you to specify a step to run when you click a nice button on the UI.

I have looked into the Jenkins [Input Step](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-input-step/) plugin, thinking I could have the teardown step at the end of the pipeline behind an input. However I find letting the pipeline run for so long inelegant.

Is there a plugin/pattern I am unaware of that would fit my needs?